# Windows App with mySQL Backend

Tags: mysql

I am trying to design a database application for my small business. I've created a number of form driven MS Access databases for use before but would like to create a permanent solution in something more advanced & common.

I was thinking of using mySQL for the database and would then program a C# or VB application to be used in Windows. I do not want or need a web based version at this time but the migration to VB.net in the far future may be something I'll look into.

I know I can use a MS Access backend for my windows application without having to install MS Office on any or all the computers the program will be run for.

But here is my question. Is it necessary to install mySQL Server on the PC hosting the database, on all the PCs accessing the database or can I just use the database file as the backend and Visual Studio will have all the necessary tools I need to access it?

If I have to install the server I may just stick with the MS Access database as the needs for an excessive amount of database storage won't ever be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to install MySQL server on the Server hosting the database. The clients would then connect via the network. You will however need a driver to access the MySQL-Server with VB.NET on the client machines. A simple DLL-File might be enough, though.

If you are looking for a file-based database solution have a look at SQLite. But you will have to watch out for concurrency issues here.